# How to make the instances of a class using a metaclass inherit from a specific superclass

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clos, mop

I'm trying to implement json serialization API for common lisp. To achieve this I've defined a metaclass called `json-class`. This metaclass defines the slot options `:ignore` which are used to ignore specific slots of the object. Since I'm using yason for the serialization process, I wanted to specialize the method `yason:encode-slots` to every object of classes that use the metaclass `json-class`. The only way I can think of to achieve this, is to make all the objects instantiated from a `json-class` of type `json-object` which can be used to specialize the methods.
The behaviour that I'm trying to replicate is the same as the one already implemented by the MOP consisting in every class using the `standard-class` producing an object of type `standard-object`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look through the source code of SBCL, you'll find that it adds `standard-object` to the list of direct superclasses inside of `shared-initialize`:

```
         (setq direct-superclasses
               (or direct-superclasses
                   (list (if (funcallable-standard-class-p class)
                             *the-class-funcallable-standard-object*
                             *the-class-standard-object*))))
```

If you wish to implicitly add a class to the direct superclasses list, it may be best to do so in an `:around` method on `shared-initialize` or `initialize-instance`.

<strike>Another option is to specialize `compute-class-precedence-list` to, for example:</strike>

`(cons my-superclass (call-next-method))`

This is what [An existing JSON MOP library](https://github.com/gschjetne/json-mop/blob/master/src/json-mop.lisp) does.

EDIT:

I think messing with `compute-class-precedence-list` to add superclasses is undefined behavior, though it usually works. I believe the best solution is to write an `:around` method for either `shared-initialize` or `initialize-instance` that first checks (using `subclassp`) whether your class is already in the inheritance chain, then adds it if not.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Closer to Mop](https://github.com/pcostanza/closer-mop):

```
(defpackage :so (:use :closer-common-lisp))
(in-package :so)

;; Define a metaclass named json-class.
;; It inherits from a standard-class
(defclass json-class (standard-class) ())
```

Specialize [`VALIDATE-SUPERCLASS`](http://metamodular.com/CLOS-MOP/validate-superclass.html) (see also [*VALIDATE-SUPERCLASS explained*](https://nl.movim.eu/?blog/phoe%40movim.eu/a9391f4b-485e-4f3a-ae02-051a5fc65ed1)).

```
(defmethod validate-superclass ((j json-class) (s standard-class)) t)
```

Then you define the base `json-object`.

```
(defclass json-object () () (:metaclass json-class))
```

For example:

```
(class-of (make-instance 'json-object))
#<JSON-CLASS SO::JSON-OBJECT>
```

The returned object is a `json-object`, an instance of `json-class`, a subclass of `standard-class`.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, if I then want to create a class with the `json-class` properties and I want it to inherit all the methods specialized for `json-object` I should define for example the class as `(defclass person (json-object) () (:metaclass json-class))` right? I also had an idea of using the `ensure-class-using-class` method to automatically add `json-object` to the `direct-superclasses` list but it does not look explicit to me. Would it be considered good design to just keep it explicit in the class definition? Or is there a better way to declare such a class?

Comment: @MPaga: I think there ought to be an easy way to default the superclasses (after all, there is for instances of `standard-class`.  But I can't work out what it should be.